# Programmatically sending an iOS app to background

Tags: ios, background

Is it possible to programmatically entering background in iOS 5 or higher? I'd like to be able to ask the user with an alertView if she'd want to proceed to run the app in background to save battery.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible to run the app in background in a indefinitely manner. In particular, it depends on the nature of your tasks. See Apple doc for this [App States and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)

Comment: I'm going to call location manager in background... AFAIK, location services are allowed to be long-running tasks in background, aren't they?

Comment: The thread you refer was opened almost 2 years ago, it could be deprecated

Comment: @AppsDev All of the details in the duplicate are still valid. There is still no App Store friendly way to programmatically send an app to the background.

Comment: @rmaddy Even if you are asking for user confirmation?

Comment: @AppsDev Correct. Just tell the user to press the Home button or tap Cancel on the alert view. You can auto-dismiss the alert of the app enters the background.